# Edit static grouped table view with multiple sections in Xcode Storyboard

Tags: xcode4, storyboard, uitableview

In XCode storyboard, it is possible to Edit the cells in table view if it's static. Is it possible to enter multiple section of data (that is in group view multiple groups) right under Storyboard, or do I need to use the data source delegate instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I quite understand the question, but if you're asking if you can do everything in Interface Builder, the answer is yes. After you've set the table content to 'static cells' in the Attribute Inspector, set the number of sections to the number of data sections you want, then modify each section by selecting the section, changing the header, footer, and number of rows. You can also quickly edit the header by double-clicking on it.

Each row in the section can be modified in the same way.

Comment: Oh, I must have been clicking the wrong place! I tried clicking the tableview with the left pane and I finally found the option for number of data sections, thanks.